# Invalid string literal '^.*\s(\d+)\s.*$'. Illegal character sequence \s' in string literal

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I want to use the below regex string:

```
private final String regex = '^.*\s(\d+)\s.*$';
```

In a Pattern:

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '^.*\s(\d+)\s.*$'. Illegal character sequence \s' in string literal.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape all the `\` characters with more `\` character of course!

```
private final String regex = '^.*\\s(\\d+)\\s.*$';
```

Comment: This feels like a duplicate question, actually.